# JHipster index.html page shows 'You are logged in as user ' even after logout

Tags: angular, jhipster

I am so stuck with this issue now for a good while.

If I login, then click on 'settings' or 'entities', then click 'logout', the home page still says i am logged in. The navbar also still shows me the 'entities' menu and the settings, session menu options. 
Tracing through the code, it seems the ngOnInit (this.principal.identity()), in the home.component is firing before the logout on the server completes. 
Is there a way we can tell the home.component to wait up.

This is where the logout is invoked in navbar.component:

```
logout() {
    this.collapseNavbar();
    this.loginService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['']);
}
```

This is the logout on the loginService:

```
logout() {
    this.authServerProvider.logout().subscribe();
    this.principal.authenticate(null);
}
```

and this is the authService provider implementation in auth-session service:

```
logout(): Observable<any> {
    // logout from the server
    console.log('logout from the server: ');
    // this.http.get(SERVER_API_URL + 'api/account', (() => {}, () => {});
    return this.http.post(SERVER_API_URL + 'api/logout', {}).map((response: Response) => {
        // to get a new csrf token call the api
        this.http.get(SERVER_API_URL + 'api/account').subscribe(() => {}, () => {});
        return response;
    });
}
```

This is the ngOnInit in the home.component

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.principal.identity().then((account) => {
        this.account = account;
    });
    this.registerAuthenticationSuccess();
}
```

This is the identity function that in turn calls getAccount rest endpoint

```
    identity(force?: boolean): Promise<any> {
    if (force === true) {
        this.userIdentity = undefined;
        this.authenticated = false;
    }

    // check and see if we have retrieved the userIdentity data from the server.
    // if we have, reuse it by immediately resolving
    if (this.userIdentity) {
        return Promise.resolve(this.userIdentity);
    }

    // retrieve the userIdentity data from the server, update the identity object, and then resolve.
    return this.account.get().toPromise().then((account) => {
        if (account) {
            this.userIdentity = account;
            this.authenticated = true;
        } else {
            this.userIdentity = null;
            this.authenticated = false;
        }
        this.authenticationState.next(this.userIdentity);
        return this.userIdentity;
    }).catch((err) => {
        this.userIdentity = null;
        this.authenticated = false;
        this.authenticationState.next(this.userIdentity);
        return null;
    });
}
```

I've put in some breakpoints, and the api/account call gets called before the logout is done on the server. Then, the api/account is called again in the home.component ngOnInit, and because it managed to get auth details from the server before the logout is completed, it lands on the home page with a message saying you are logged in.

I would be very grateful for any pointers, thoughts and ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution, sorry, I'm pretty new to UI, so this may be old news for seasoned pro's :)

I left the auth-session.service as above.

I changed the navbar.component to use a Promise:

```
logout() {
    this.collapseNavbar();
    this.loginService.logout().then((response) => this.router.navigate(['']))
}
```

and the login.service changed to have a Promise, which will wait for the logout:

```
logout() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.authServerProvider.logout().subscribe((data) => {
            this.principal.identity(true).then((account) => {
                resolve(data);
            });
        }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
         });
    });
  }
}
```

The home page now shows clean if you sign-out. This could be added to JHipster as an enhancement. 
Also, thank you to [these authors and this page for the inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351142/angular2-navigate-after-observable-is-complete)